# Knockout таблицы и IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockoutjs

Изначально у меня есть несколько столбцов в таблице, но когда я уменьшаю размер окна, некоторые столбцы скрываются с помощью «ko if». IE удаляет эти столбцы, но не растягивает таблицу на всю ее ширину, реагируя так, как если бы эти столбцы не были удалены.

Это проверяется с использованием последней строки в таблице, которая растягивается на всю ширину таблицы. Первоначально количество столбцов равно 7, а после уменьшения равно 4. Если после сокращения установить «colspan» равен 7, то линия будет растянута до нормальной ширины.